# Как обновить страницу из javascript?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Если я в javascript пишу

```
$.get('test.php?param1=6');
```

запрос выполняется как-то "молча", т.е. я вижу в сниффере, что страница загрузилась, но в браузере она не изменяется.

Как сделать, чтобы контент заменился в браузере?

Пробовал ещё вот так:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?param1=6",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

но, похоже, никакой разницы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get('test.php', {
 param1: 6
}, function(data) {
 $('body').html(data); // вставляем в <body> ответ запроса

 history.pushState({}, '', 'test.php'); // меняем URL
});
```

Comment: Это, видимо, тот самый жесткий подход, о которой писал Deonis) Почти то, что нужно, но при таком подходе ссылка не меняется в строке адреса и source страницы соответственно от старой страницы. 

Но принцип сразу стал понятен, спасибо. Кстати, начинаю понимать всё прелесть ajax. Сразу появилось желание всё переписать совсем по-другому :)

Comment: @Isaev, обновил пост. Теперь меняется и URL.

Comment: то, что нужно, благодарю!

Comment: @ModaL, всё равно чуть не то... можно как-то сделать, чтобы это был полноценный переход? В браузере предыдущую страницу включаешь, меняется только адресс, а сама страница остаётся прежняя)

Comment: @Isaev, потому что много чего не учтено. Писал для себя ajax навигацию. Можете забрать - http://pastebin.com/qtVB6f77

Использовать так:

>> <a href="/test.php" onclick="nav.go(this); return false">test</a>

+ содержимое нужно обернуть в div id="page" и в скрипте site.ru заменить на свой.

Comment: неожиданно нашёл вот такое простое решение:

    location.href = url;

и всё работает, как ни странно, что плохого в таком подходе?

А ваша навигация будет получается работать, даже если не всю страницу перегружаем, а тело какого-то отдельного тега?

Comment: @Isaev, >> location.href = url;

Это уже не AJAX, а обычная переадресация. Проще тогда уж <a href="/test.php">test</a>

>> А ваша навигация будет получается работать даже если не всю страницу перегружаем, а тело какого-то отдельного тега?

Не совсем понял что имеется ввиду.

Answer (score 4):

[@Isaev](/users/20392/isaev), похоже, что вы, как пилот-аматор, который прочитал инструкцию о том, как нужно взлетать, но уже в воздухе выяснилось, что о посадке он ничего не знает. Ajax-запросом, вы не только можете передавыть какие-то данные на сервер, но и получать данные ответом. 
Почитайте внимательно о методе [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) или вообще [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (*в частности о callback-функции **success*** ), если будете использовать jQuery или, если собираетесь писать на чистом JS, то вообще всю [статейку по XMLHttpRequest](http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) можете проштудировать.

Comment: Спасибо, что собрали все ссылки в одном месте. Я это уже не раз перечитывал за последние два дня, может что-то пропустил (последнюю только не находил, отлично расписано всё!).

Проблема немного не в этом, я делал и с callback-функцией success и в ней получаю тот же ответ в виде текста страницы, которую я хочу видеть. Наверное, я просто криво поставил вопрос... Вопрос в том, как текущую страницу заменить на ту, которую я в ответе получил?

Comment: @Isaev, для замены или добавления контента - методы html(), append(), prepend(), text() и т.д. А вот "*текущую страницу заменить на ту, которую я в ответе получил*" - это подход жёсткий )) Всё-равно, что пилить ветку, на которой сидишь. Надеюсь, что это так же относится к криво поставленному вопросу.

Comment: понимаю о чём вы) нужно было поставить опрос ещё проще.
Когда мы кликаем по ссылке на странице, грузится другая страница. грубо говоря нужно эмулировать клик по ссылке

Comment: @Isaev, судя по комментарию на ответ @ModaL, для полного счастья, вам нехватает History API. Можете взять на вооружение [этот плагинчик][1]. Там же найдёте [описание на русском][2], если с инглишем туго.

   [1]:https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API
   [2]:https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API#%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%99

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = new_url
```